# The best sale database structure for a book store

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm, performance, database-design

I have two database structure:

**#1: Each book is a row:**

```
// sale 
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | book_id | customer_id |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 1  | 5       | 123         |
| 2  | 5       | 123         |
| 3  | 9       | 123         |
| 4  | 4       | 456         |
| 5  | 12      | 456         |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

**#2: There is a number column:**

```
// sale 
+----+---------+-------------+--------+
| id | book_id | customer_id | number |
+----+---------+-------------+--------+
| 1  | 5       | 123         | 2      |
| 2  | 9       | 123         | 1      |
| 3  | 4       | 456         | 1      |
| 4  | 12      | 456         | 1      |
+----+---------+-------------+--------+
```

As you can see, the first one has a different existence for each book *(which would be good for some ideas in the future, i.e returned books which need returned date, or giving some discounts on the multiple procurement of the same book or whatever)*. But the second one seems more optimal, since it has fewer rows.

Anyway, which one is your recommendation? I personally like the first one and I'm just worried about the redundancy. Has the first structure redundancy?

Comment: A database for a book store will have many tables - dozens at least.  That said, a table for storing sales is going to have what you call "redundancy", but that's just the nature of the beast, because that table is tracking "events" - "on this date, at this time, at this store, this customer bought this book for this price and was checked out by this employee."  You see?

Answer (score 0):

In my idea the first solution is right. (**and the second is wrong**)

**Why**:
Based on your explanation, each sale is a **new valid object** (or record) with it's **own data** and it's **own existence**.

As you said, each sale object (record) has book_id, customer_id, sale_date, seller_id (or employee_id), sale_price, sale_discount, sale_description, sale_payment_method and etc.

There are only book_id and customer_id looks in common (**only** when one customer by the same book twice or more) and absolutely it is not redundancy.

If you merge them as second solution, you encountered a lot of difficulties in designing the rest of your design and in implementation.

Just a little improvement to your design: 
You can have two entities like **purchase_invoice** and **purchase_invoice_row** and then you can have a number of sales in purchase_invoice_row. (the number of any books that sales at the time). I mean that it is better to manage the sale information with two entities. (not one)

Answer (score 0):

I think your second model, though it's too simplified, is a better choice. However, as I wrote, it's too simplified. Here is how I would probably design it:

```
Orders
    order_Id int auto increment primary key
    order_date datetime
    order_customer_id int (fk to customers)
    order_seller_id int (fk to sellers)
    unique index on order_date, order_customer_id and order_seller_id

OrderDetails
    OD_order_detail_id int auto increment primary key
    OD_order_id int (fk to orders)
    OD_item_id int (fk to books) 
    OD_pricePerUnit decimal (this is to support special discounts)
    OD_quantity int
    unique index on od_order_id, od_item_id
```

Now, for returns returns and stuff like that you have another table:

```
Returns
    return_id int auto increment primary key
    return_order_detail_id int (fk to order) 
    return_date datetime
    return_quantity int (the number of items returned)
    return_comment varchar(1000) (you will want to know why it's returned)
    unique index on return_order_detail id, return_date
```

If you are a Codd fanatic and want to avoid surrogate keys, you can loose the auto increment primary keys and instead use the unique indexes. However, this means you will have to carry the values of the columns specified in the unique indexes through all the related tables:

```
Orders
    order_Id int auto increment (just to have a numeric reference)
    order_date datetime
    order_customer_id int (fk to customers)
    order_seller_id int (fk to sellers)
    primary key on order_date, order_customer_id and order_seller_id

OrderDetails
    OD_order_detail_id int auto increment (just to have a numeric reference)
    OD_order_date int (fk to orders)
    OD_order_customer_id int (fk to orders)
    OD_order_seller_id int (fk to orders)
    OD_item_id int (fk to books) 
    OD_pricePerUnit decimal (this is to support special discounts)
    OD_quantity int
    primary key on od_order_id, od_item_id
```